# Magento - Set default value for attribute field

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, attributes, customer, custom-options

I created a new customer attribute with the select tag and the various options. When I try to create a new customer, this field returns the vacuum to me as the default value.

[image]

I want to force the default option in the select field of the attribute with the php. How can I do?

The module with which I create custom attributes for customers is called "Manage Customer Attributes Extension"

Thanks

Comment: There might be an option while creating custom customer attribute to set default value. You can share screen shot of screen where you are creating attribute

Comment: This is true man thanks, but since in my admin I will have several users I would like this default value to change. For example: if (getUserId() == 2) {setDefaultvalue}

Comment: Here  "if (getUserId() == 2) " user id is customer id or admin user id?

Comment: admin user id..

Comment: FYI, customer attribute value is associated with the customer cannot change as per admin user, if you to show different values as per admin then you need to change in core customer admin module by adding some static conditions .

Comment: Perfect, the only thing is that I could not find the php function that forces the change of the default selection of the attribute. Any suggestions for this? Thanks for the moment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Magento's default customer Account Information tab to see this information in admin then you can see this file:

/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tab/Account.php

In this file you can see these 2 lines which set the form data in admin:

```
$form->setValues($customer->getData());
$this->setForm($form);
```

So you can add below code above these lines to update any customer attribute value to be seen in admin Account Information tab:

```
$admin_user_session = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
$adminuserId = $admin_user_session->getUser()->getUserId();
if($adminuserId ==68){
//like below code you can set particular customer attribute value as per your requirement 
$customer->setFirstname('test');

}
```

Note: This code will only manipulate the customer data before showing on Account information tab it will not update the actual customer data, if you want to update use

`$customer->save();` after the above code

Also this is the core file, so please override in your module as not recommended to modify core files.